# Sniffing network traffic for signs of viruses/spyware

Tags: networking, system-administration, virus, sniffing, spyware

How can I connect a system to a network and sniff for virus/spyware related traffic?  I'd like to plug in a network cable, fire up an appropriate tool sand have it scan the data for any signs of problems.  I don't expect this to find everything, and this is not to prevent initial infection but to help determine if there is anything trying to actively infect other system/causing network problems.

Running a regular network sniffer and manually looking through the results is no good unless the traffic is really obvious,but I havn't been able to find any tool to scan a network data stream automatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I highly recommend running [Snort](http://www.snort.org/) on a machine somewhere near the core of your network, and span (mirror) one (or more) ports from somewhere along your core network path to the machine in question.

Snort has the ability to scan network traffic it sees, and automatically notify you via various methods if it sees something suspicious. This could even be taken further, if desired, to automatically disconnect devices, et cetera, if it finds something.

Answer (score 12):

1. Use [snort](http://www.snort.org/): An open source network intrusion prevention and detection system.
2. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), formerly ethereal is a great tool, but will not notify you or scan for viruses. Wireshark is a free packet sniffer and protocol analyzer.
3. Use the netstat -b command to see which processes have which ports open.
4. Use [CPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) to see a list of ports and the associated programs, and have the ability to close those ports.
5. Download a free anti-virus program such as [free AVG](http://free.avg.com/).
6. Setup your firewall more tightly.
7. Setup a gateway computer to let all network traffic go through.  Take the above recommendataions to the gateway computer instead.  You will be checking your whole network instead of just your one computer.

Answer (score 3):

You can make [Snort](http://www.snort.org/) scan traffic for viruses. I think this will be the best solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

For watching local network traffic your best bet (with a decent switch) is to set your switch to route all packets out a specific interface (as well as whatever interface it would normally send). This lets you monitor the entire network by dumping traffic down a specific port.

On a 100 megabit network, however, you'll want a gigabit port on your switch to plug it into, or to filter on protocol (e.g. trim out HTTP, FTP, printing, traffic from the fileserver, etc.), or your switch's buffers are going to fill up pretty much instantly and it'll start dropping whatever packets it needs to (and your network performance will die).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that approach is that most networks today are on switches, not hubs. So, if you plug a machine with a packet sniffer into the switch, it will only be able to see traffic to and from the sniffing machine; and network broadcasts.

Comment: Spanning (mirroring) a major backbone circuit solves this issue. Regardless of whether it's a switch or not.

Comment: I didn't know that. What kind of hardware do you need to make that work? Is it all in the switch?

Comment: Yes, it's a function of the switch. Most modern managed (as opposed to "dumb") switches have this capability.

Comment: So, as long as you're on a managed switch and the IT department will let you touch it, this can work.

Comment: I would expect anyone to ask this question to at least in some form, be responsible for the network, or work with people who are responsible for the network. IDS/security often go hand in hand with maintaining the network :)

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to [Ferruccio's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124745/sniffing-network-traffic-for-signs-of-virusesspyware#124768) comment you will need to find some method of getting around your switches.

A number of network switches have the option of setting up port mirrors, so that all traffic (regardless of the destination) will be copied, or "mirrored", to a nominated port. If you could configure your switch to do this then you would be able to attach your network sniffer here.

Answer (score 0):

[Network Magic](http://www.networkmagic.com/), if you don't mind something that's not open source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IDS, hardware or software 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion-detection_system